# reason for separating memory into banks IN PIC microcontroler

Tags: memory, assembly, microcontroller, pic

I wonder why Data memory is separated into BANKS in PIC microcontroller family? I've done a lot of search but only thing I could find that it is separated into 4 banks and  each of which is 128 bytes long. I could not find the reason behind it. I mean there must be some advantages of partitioning the memory.

Comment: Growth.  Better chip technology allowed adding more registers.  But they could not change the instruction format anymore.  Which uses 7 bits for the register selection (thus 128 bytes), requiring banks to address more.

Answer (score 1):

The memory location is encoded into the program words. This means that you can often get away with a single program word instead of two (one for the instruction and one for the address)

The downside is that you either need to make the program words 2 bits longer to have a flat memory space, or split the RAM into 4 banks.

The first option is especially impractical if you want to be able to add members to the chip family with 2 or 4 or 8 times the RAM